# Serial Port Problems on Windows Server 2008

Tags: serial-port, windows-server-2008, gsm

I've an application that uses GSM commands sent over a serial port to a GSM ModeM.

The application works just fine on Windows XP, 7 etc., but sometimes it does not connect to the serial port on Windows Server 2008.

I tried to check using an application called Tera Term, but when I try and connect it to the port where the ModeM is supposed to be connected to, I get an error saying the COM1 port is not available ( it is the required port ).

This could indicate that the COM port is busy or occupied...and indeed when I try to rename the port, I get a Windows Warning that port is opened by some other application and renaming it can have consequences etc.etc...

How do I find out which, if any, application is using the COM port? I tried Portmon, but it remains greyed out in the Ports/capture area...so I cannot use it to find out what's happening with it?

Could anyone please tell me if there's a problem with the COM port detection in Windows Server 2008? Or if it's a problem with Tera Term/ PortMon that they're not able to detect the COM port?

This issue is baffling..kindly help me on this.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find out which application is opening or accessing the COM1 serial port, or at least figure out what is going on. It has been  while since I last had to do this so I don't remember the details of how to go about doing that.

If you decide to do this, I recommend running Process Monitor on a system that you are able to get this to work successfully first. That way you can see what a "normal" system looks like and compare it to what you are getting on the Windows Server 2008 system.